# How can I join non-overlapping TimeSeries so that the gap between any two is considered to be Missing data?

Tags: time-series, data-structures

I have a set of time series sampled at one second intervals.
For example,

```
  ts1 = TimeSeries[Table[k,{k,0,10}],{0,10}],
  ts2 = TimeSeries[Table[k^2/10,{k,0,10}],{15,25}]
```

The series do not overlap and are separated by gaps of many seconds.

**How to join them to form a single time series such that any attempt to sample that series in a gap between the initial series results in a [`Missing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Missing.html) value?**

Comment: **What have your tried?** The community [expects the following](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) from you: 
✅: A clear description of an on-topic problem or goal.
❌: A minimal working *Wolfram Language* code example, formatted, easy to *copy&paste*, in [Raw InputForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/RawInputForm.html). 
❌. An example of what you expect as output.
❌. Some proof of minimal *Mathematica* knowledge. 
❌. Minimum due diligence: Share how you have searched the site and documentation, your attempts and reasons to believe an answer exists.

Answer (score 3):

You can join the two [`TimeSeries`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeries.html) using [`TimeSeriesInsert`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesInsert.html). Now to fill the gap with [`Missing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Missing.html), I recommend using [`TimeSeriesResample`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesResample.html) with the [`ResamplingMethod`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResamplingMethod.html) option set to [`None`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/None.html)

```
tsj = TimeSeriesResample[
   TimeSeriesInsert[ ts1, ts2 ]
   , ResamplingMethod -> None
]
```

now

```
tsj["Values"]

(* {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, Missing[], Missing[], Missing[], Missing[], 0, 1/10, 2/5, 9/10, 8/5, 5/2, 18/5, 49/10, 32/5, 81/10, 10} *)
```

You can choose other methods too

```
ListLinePlot[  
   {
      TimeSeriesResample[
         TimeSeriesInsert[ ts1, ts2 ]
         , ResamplingMethod -> {"Constant",5}
      ],
      tsj
   }
   , Joined -> True
   , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
]
```

[image]